# How to describe what conditions are to be met, and if they aren't, keep going through a list

Tags: prolog

So I would like to know what would be a declarative way of looking at this specific part of a problem I'm trying to solve:

```
% create_arcs(CONNECTIONS_IN, NODES_IN, ARCS_OUT).  
% Create arcs - makes a list of arcs(NODE_ID_1, NODE_ID_2)...
create_arcs([], _, _).
create_arcs([A-B | T], [H|NODES], LISTARCS) :-
    ensure_arcs(A,B,H, LISTARCS, LISTARCS2),
    create_arcs(T, NODES, LISTARCS2).

%ensure_arcs(NODE_A, NODE_B, NODELIST, LISTARCSIN, LISTARCSOUT)
%builds a list of arcs TODO works WRONG when arc already was in the input. It should fail, but it just checks that is a member and moves on. So basically it works when arcs are new, because they are added properly, but not when arcs were already found (and as per the exercise it should fail and try another permutation).
ensure_arcs(A,B,NODES, LISTARCSIN, LISTARCSIN):-
    member(enum(NODE_ID_A, A), NODES),
    member(enum(NODE_ID_B, B), NODES),
    REMAINDER is abs(NODE_ID_A-NODE_ID_B),
    member(enum(REMAINDER,_), LISTARCSIN), !.

ensure_arcs(A,B,NODES, LISTARCSIN,[enum(REMAINDER, A-B) | LISTARCSIN]):-
    member(enum(NODE_ID_A, A), NODES),
    member(enum(NODE_ID_B, B), NODES),
    REMAINDER is abs(NODE_ID_A-NODE_ID_B).
```

The idea here, if I were able to get this right, is to define the conditions that have to be satisfied and if they aren't, keep travelling the input list.

So, trying to explain myself properly, the idea is, if it does not meet every condition, it should fail and keep traveling the list. If it fails, it should return successfully. How far off I am? Is this still an imperative way of looking at things?

I need to know how would I go to travel the list when the conditions are not met, and if they are not, try another option; otherwise if they are met, stop travelling.

**Second edit:**

So I changed code a bit, but I don't see `maplist(dif(enum(REMAINDER,_)), ListArcsInput),` ever saying "no" so it's very confusing. It should fail if what I put inside the dif/2 is already in the ListArcsInput, right??

Code for reference:

```
pairs_nodes_arcs(_, [],_).
pairs_nodes_arcs([], _, _).
pairs_nodes_arcs([A-B | T], [H|NODES], LISTARCS) :-
    member(enum(NODE_ID_A, A), H),
    member(enum(NODE_ID_B, B), H),
    REMAINDER is abs(NODE_ID_A-NODE_ID_B),
    arcs_are_repeated([A-B | T], [H|NODES], REMAINDER,LISTARCS).
    %maplist(dif(enum(REMAINDER,_)), LISTARCSIN),


    %pairs_nodes_arcs(T, [H|NODES], LISTARCS2),
    %pairs_nodes_arcs([A-B | T], NODES, []).

arcs_are_repeated([A-B | T],[H|NODES],REMAINDER,ListArcsInput):-
    maplist(dif(enum(REMAINDER,_)), ListArcsInput),
    pairs_nodes_arcs(T, [H|NODES], [enum(REMAINDER, A-B) | ListArcsInput]).

arcs_are_repeated([A-B | T],[H|NODES],ElementoListaArcos,ListArcsInput):-
    pairs_nodes_arcs([A-B | T], NODES, []).
```

And trace:

```
Call:'__aux_maplist/2_dif+1'([enum(1, a-b)], enum(1, _G3643))
 Call:dif:dif(enum(1, _G3643), enum(1, a-b))
 Exit:dif:dif(enum(1, _G3677), enum(1, a-b))
 Call:'__aux_maplist/2_dif+1'([], enum(1, _G3677))
 Exit:'__aux_maplist/2_dif+1'([], enum(1, _G3677))
 Exit:'__aux_maplist/2_dif+1'([enum(1, a-b)], enum(1, _G3677))
 Call:create_arcs([], [[enum(1, a), enum(2, b), enum(3, c)], [enum(1, a), enum(3, c), enum(2, b)], [enum(2, b), enum(1, a), enum(3, c)], [enum(2, b), enum(3, c), enum(1, a)], [enum(3, c), enum(1, a), enum(2, b)], [enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)]], [enum(1, b-c), enum(1, a-b)])
 Exit:create_arcs([], [[enum(1, a), enum(2, b), enum(3, c)], [enum(1, a), enum(3, c), enum(2, b)], [enum(2, b), enum(1, a), enum(3, c)], [enum(2, b), enum(3, c), enum(1, a)], [enum(3, c), enum(1, a), enum(2, b)], [enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)]], [enum(1, b-c), enum(1, a-b)])
```

**I couldn't get maplist to work but I could get dif, so I'm traveling "by hand" the list, that meaning I do myself and compare with dif every element. Seems to be working so far?**

---

**Edit**: This is the trace that I obtain as of right now with all my code, in which, what I would like is, if the follow case happens, it should NOT take/accept/keep with the current "branch" and since it did find something "twice" in the output list, it should skip, backtrack, and try another possibility.

```
Call:create_arcs([b-c], [[enum(1, a), enum(2, b), enum(3, c)], [enum(1, a), enum(3, c), enum(2, b)], [enum(2, b), enum(1, a), enum(3, c)], [enum(2, b), enum(3, c), enum(1, a)], [enum(3, c), enum(1, a), enum(2, b)], [enum(3, c), enum(2, b), enum(1, a)]], [enum(1, a-b)])
 Call:ensure_arcs(b, c, [enum(1, a), enum(2, b), enum(3, c)], [enum(1, a-b)], _G3600)
 Call:lists:member(enum(_G3555, b), [enum(1, a), enum(2, b), enum(3, c)])
 Exit:lists:member(enum(2, b), [enum(1, a), enum(2, b), enum(3, c)])
 Call:lists:member(enum(_G3558, c), [enum(1, a), enum(2, b), enum(3, c)])
 Exit:lists:member(enum(3, c), [enum(1, a), enum(2, b), enum(3, c)])
 Call:_G3607 is abs(2-3)
 Exit:1 is abs(2-3)


 Call:lists:member(enum(1, _G3567), [enum(1, a-b)])
 Exit:lists:member(enum(1, a-b), [enum(1, a-b)])
```

So that two lines, when there was nothing on the list, or there is, but it does not match, works properly: it goes to my other definition of ensure_arcs, and adds it to the output list. Now I want to, if there IS a matching member, to fail, or backtrack, or whatever. Doing it forcefully seems wrong (I'm sure there has to be some kind of halt or FAIL or whatever, but I would like to know how to program it so that, if it DOES match, to let it know it is not an accepted answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are already very close to the solution.

I have the following suggestions to make your predicate more **declarative**, that is, as you correctly say, describe **what holds**.

My first suggestion is about **names** of your predicates. For good declarative names, choose *nouns* and *adjectives*, and **avoid imperatives**. This is because nice relational predicates can be used in *all directions*, whereas an imperative always suggests a particular directions or mode of use.

For example, instead of `create_arcs/3`, a more descriptive and declarative name would be: **`pairs_nodes_arcs/3`**. This correctly suggests that you can use this predicate also for example if the arcs are already specified.

My second suggestion is about actually carrying out the implied generality by using general relations throughout your program. In your specific case, check out your Prolog system's **CLP(FD) constraints** and replace low-level arithmetic predicates over integers with the CLP(FD) constraints **(#=)/2** and others. These relations are *reversible* and yield much more general programs in addition to preserving your program's performance in cases that can be handled by lower-level arithmetic.

Third, retain the achieved generality by **avoiding !/0** and related non-monotonic predicates. In your case, you are already quite close to this desirable state. Simply remove the single occurrence of `!/0` to obtain *all solutions*. (Using `!/0` impurely cuts away candidates that you may need on backtracking.)

By honoring these principles, you will obtain a quite general program that lets you:

- **test** given solutions
- **complete** partially instantiated solutions
- **generate** all solutions.

All of this follows naturally from a single declarative specification of **what** a solutions looks like.

Note that Prolog will *automatically* go through all possibilities until it finds a solution that *satisfies all constraints*. Focus on a clear description of the properties that must be met. It is not necessary to describe what *isn't* a solution.

**EDIT**: There is of course a way to cause the current branch of the computation to **fail**. All it takes is to post a goal that is clearly **false**. The aptly named built-in predicate `false/0` does this, and so does any other goal that certainly does not hold, such as for example `0=1`.

However, a much cleaner approch in your case is to explicitly state what **must hold** for a solution. In your case, it seems to be necessary to talk about terms or integers that are **different**. To denote that arbitrary terms are **different**, use the `dif/2` predicate, see [prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif). As you are reasoning over integers, you can also use the [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) constraints `(#\=)/2` or `all_distinct/1` to state this.

For example, to state that a relation only holds if `enum(R,_)` does **not** occur in `Ls`, use:

```
maplist(dif(enum(R,_)), Ls)
```

This is only true **if**, for each `L` in `Ls`, `dif(enum(R,_), L)` is **true**.

Use this to *declaratively* express that a term *does not* occur in a list. Note: This will retain the **relational nature** of your program. For example, it will work also if the term is (only or even, depending on how you look at it) *partially* instantiated.

I leave the more specific case of using CLP(FD) constraints (instead of `dif/2`, which does not take into account domain-specific knowledge about integers) as an easy exercise.

Comment: I shall 100% do first and third points, as for #=/2, it's the first time I've seen it so I will look into it to see how to implement it! Now, your last paragraph is what might seal the deal for me. I NEED to see it so I'm going to trace the program step by step to see where it's going, but I don't think I had in mind that it would go both through solutions that satisfie the constraint and thus that do not. But I wanted to ask you something else

Comment: Does it make sense from a programmatic point of view to, as I'm trying, "get" all possible combination with a setof, and then travel through that list to see which ones satisfy the constraints? Because the amount of possibilities grow simply too much for even small lists

Comment: `setof/3` by itself will *not reduce* the number of solutions. The "normal" Prolog way is to specify the constraints, and let *backtracking* automatically find all solutions. You can use `setof/3` to implement Prolog or a variant of this backtracking *within* your program. This is one way to implement *other* search strategies, different from Prolog's chronological backtracking. If you see too many possibilites, it is best to **reorder** your goals such that relevant constraints are stated *as soon as possible*. For this reason, I recommend CLP(FD) constraints: State the constraints **early**.

Comment: For example, the CL(FD) constraint `REMAINDER #= abs(NODE_ID_A-NODE_ID_B)` can be stated as the *first* goal of your predicate. This may help to significantly reduce the search space.

Comment: No, the problem is the way I'm attacking the problem itself. I do not know how to do what you say for ALL conditions. It would be one thing for one, but for all of them, my idea was: get every possibility, and then try and see if it fits. I am not able to see the problem the other way around: see what meets this criteria, because in a sense I don't know how to SET all possibilities at once. That's why I tried first generating solutions then looking if they are valid. This is because of the problem itself, I do not know to solve it beforehand, algorithmically, as to speak

Comment: Alright so I am trying to follow what you say, @mat and I know you have already devoted quite some time to my problem, but if you could see my edit, I think it's the main thing I do not follow: I am generating that solution, but I do not know how to make a condition so that it says: if this IS a member, it does not match the condition, thus, try another possibility. So it is a problem of how I've made the rules, specifically the member one, I know how to do it when it does not succed, I add a member, but if it does, I don't want it to return true.

Comment: I have added more information about expressing disequality of terms. Use the `dif/2` predicate to describe the condition "two terms are different". When reasoning over integers, you can use the CLP(FD) constraint `(#\=)/2` to take domain-specific knowledge into account.

Comment: So I've been trying to use that maplist(dif(enum(REMAINDER,_)), LISTARCSIN) you told me about, and every single query I'm manually doing, maplist returns true. So for example this dumb query returns true: maplist(dif([enum(1,a-b)]), [enum(1, a-b)]). I think I'm missing something because when I read the documentation, it looks exactly as to what I want. I put an edit2 to the post. Once again, I'm sorry to be such a bother, and I feel very grateful for your help @mat

Comment: You are getting increasingly closer to a nice and general solution. For example, the predicate names are now already much more declarative. The remaining issues are simply a few misconceptions. For example, regarding the sample goal you showed, you are simply accidentally using a superfluous number of brackets. The following fails as expected: `?- maplist(dif(enum(1,a-b)), [enum(1, a-b)]).` Notice that there are **no** brackets arounds the *first* argument of `dif/2`. In your code, there are also a few singleton variables currently. Please carefully think through what to state about them.

Comment: It was indeed a problem of brackets, I managed to see that even if it took a while. I am aware and worried about the singleton variables, but as of now, I'm kicking them down the road to keep focused on a few things. I will now study your answer once again! It takes me a while to do but it's more than worth it every time.